# How to center three divs horizontally within a parent div?

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been frequently asked but I can never seem to get it to work. Can you tell me what's wrong?

I have three divs within a #container div, which I want to centre side by side. The #container is 1000px wide (I want to keep it that way). Here is my code:

```css
#container {
  margin-top: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
}
.related-article {
  background-color: #D6A400;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.related-article > img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.related-article > h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Abel, serif;
  margin-bottom: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#right {
  float: right;
}
#left {
  float: left;
}
#center {
  margin-left: 385px;
  margin-right: 385px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>Here's what you'll do!</h2>
  <div id="left">
    <a href="#" class="related-article first" align="middle">
      <img src="download.jpeg" alt="T-rex">
      <h3>Constructing amazing fossils you never even dreamed of</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <a href="#" class="related-article second" align="middle">
      <img src="fossil-fish-10-lg.jpg" alt="Fish">
      <h3>Studying ancient marine biology</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <a href="#" class="related-article third" align="middle">
      <img src="fossil.turtle2.jpg" alt="Turtle">
      <h3>Uncovering the world's greatest mysteries</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

All help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that quite simple using flexbox:

```css
#container {
/*     margin-top: 500px; */
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.related-article {
  background-color: #D6A400;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.related-article > img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.related-article > h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Abel, serif;
  margin-bottom: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

}
#container {
    width: 1000px;
}

.related-article {
  background-color: #D6A400;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.related-article > img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.related-article > h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Abel, serif;
  margin-bottom: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.box {
  margin-right: 10px;
    width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
  }

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <h2>Here's what you'll do!</h2>
        <div class="flex-container">
        <div id="left" class="box">
          <a href="#" class="related-article first" align="middle">
            <img src="download.jpeg" alt="T-rex">
            <h3>Constructing amazing fossils you never even dreamed of</h3>
          </a>
          </div>
          <div id="center"  class="box">
          <a href="#" class="related-article second" align="middle">
            <img src="fossil-fish-10-lg.jpg" alt="Fish">
            <h3>Studying ancient marine biology</h3>
          </a>
          </div>
          <div id="right"  class="box">
          <a href="#" class="related-article third" align="middle">
            <img src="fossil.turtle2.jpg" alt="Turtle">
            <h3>Uncovering the world's greatest mysteries</h3>
          </a>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution using `display: flex`. Read more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

1. Apply `display: flex` to the container
2. Add `flex: 1` to all the child's which are to be centered horizontally.

```css
h2 {
  margin-top: 500px;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
#container div {
  flex: 1;
}
.related-article {
  background-color: #D6A400;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.related-article > img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.related-article > h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Abel, serif;
  margin-bottom: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Here's what you'll do!</h2>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <a href="#" class="related-article first" align="middle">
      <img src="download.jpeg" alt="T-rex">
      <h3>Constructing amazing fossils you never even dreamed of</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <a href="#" class="related-article second" align="middle">
      <img src="fossil-fish-10-lg.jpg" alt="Fish">
      <h3>Studying ancient marine biology</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <a href="#" class="related-article third" align="middle">
      <img src="fossil.turtle2.jpg" alt="Turtle">
      <h3>Uncovering the world's greatest mysteries</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove all the floats and replace them with :

```
display: inline-block;
```

Also, as much as i have tried, with that spacing between divs, you wont be able to display them the right way. Make the space between the #left, #center and #right divs less than 50px, or work with percentage(%).

Answer (score 2):

You may use `display:table` for that..

You can have Parent div with style

```
display:table
```

and your 3 child divs as

```
display:table-cell
```

```css
#container {
  margin-top: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
}
.related-article {
  background-color: #D6A400;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.related-article > img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.related-article > h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Abel, serif;
  margin-bottom: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#container {
  margin-top: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  display: table;
}
.related-article {
  background-color: #D6A400;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.related-article > img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.related-article > h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Abel, serif;
  margin-bottom: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#left,
#right,
#center {
  display: table-cell;
}
#center {
  margin-left: 385px;
  margin-right: 385px;
}
h2 {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>Here's what you'll do!</h2>
  <div id="left">
    <a href="#" class="related-article first" align="middle">
      <img src="download.jpeg" alt="T-rex">
      <h3>Constructing amazing fossils you never even dreamed of</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <a href="#" class="related-article second" align="middle">
      <img src="fossil-fish-10-lg.jpg" alt="Fish">
      <h3>Studying ancient marine biology</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <a href="#" class="related-article third" align="middle">
      <img src="fossil.turtle2.jpg" alt="Turtle">
      <h3>Uncovering the world's greatest mysteries</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `float` from and add `display: inline-block` to all three, then add `text-align: center;` to the container.

Comment: Lol you took my words see here https://jsfiddle.net/jsusLxoy/

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and add **float:left** to your right,left and center div and reduce your **margin left and right** of center div.

```
#right {
float: left;
}
#left {
float: left;
}
#center {
margin-left: 85px;
margin-right: 85px;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead adding center, left and right. Use ul and set the width of li in percentage. It will improve the code and reduce the css code.

The codepen url is http://codepen.io/SESN/pen/pbbjrb

CSS

```
#container { width: 100%; }
.ulContainer { margin: 0px auto; list-style: none; width: 80%; }
.ulContainer li { width: 33.33%; float: left; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
        <h2>Here's what you'll do!</h2>
  <ul class="ulContainer">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="related-article first" align="middle">
            <img src="download.jpeg" alt="T-rex">
            <h3>Constructing amazing fossils you never even dreamed of</h3>
          </a>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="related-article second" align="middle">
            <img src="fossil-fish-10-lg.jpg" alt="Fish">
            <h3>Studying ancient marine biology</h3>
          </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="related-article third" align="middle">
            <img src="fossil.turtle2.jpg" alt="Turtle">
            <h3>Uncovering the world's greatest mysteries</h3>
          </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
        </div>
```